# creating wp query with posts with specific category

Tags: wp-query

Im running a specific wp_query to show the thumbnails in a slider of a specific category.

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query ('showposts=2', 'category_name=Events'); ?>
```

This doesnt appear to be working, am i missing array at the beginning somewhere

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query array('showposts=2', 'category_name=Events'); ?>
```

the above seemed to crash it.

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use either:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=2&category_name=events');
```

or

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'category_name' => 'events', // this is the category SLUG
));
```

---

**// EDIT**
**Please note** that `category_name` actually is the category **slug** (which is for one-word names originally the same). It is not the actual name (maybe having spaces, special characters etc. in it), though. In your case, where you just want to specifiy a certain category, you can do this either by means of the ID (`cat=42`) or the slug (`category_name=events`).

If you really want/have to use the name, you have to use `get_cat_ID('Category Name')`, for instance like so:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'cat' => get_cat_ID('Events'),
));
```